Does restricting the eigenvalues of Hermitian matrices to the interval $[0,2\pi)$ make the exponential map to the unitary group bijective?
Let $U \in U(n)$ be a generic unitary matrix. Since the unitary group $U(n)$ is compact and connected, I know that the exponential map is surjective, i.e. that every $U \in U(n)$ has the form $U = e^{iH}$ for some Hermitian matrix $H \in \mathfrak{u}(n)$ (using physicist's convention). Furthermore, since both $U$ and $H$ are normal, by the spectral theorem they have the forms $U = V\text{diag}(e^{i\theta_j})V^\dagger$ and $H = V\text{diag}(\theta_j)V^\dagger$ with $\theta_j \in \mathbf{R}$ and eigenvectors given by the columns of $V$.
I can also see that the exponential map is not injective over the domain $\mathfrak{u}(n)$, since e.g. $H' = V\text{diag}(\theta_j+2\pi k_j)V^\dagger$ describes a whole family of Hermitian matrices that all map to the same unitary matrix, for any choices of the integers $k_j$.
My question is: does restricting every $\theta_j \in [0,2\pi)$ make the exponential map bijective? It seems like the answer should be yes, but I want to make sure since I'm not an expert on Lie groups.

Yes, the map $H\mapsto e^{iH}$ is bijective from self-adjoint matrices with eigenvalues in $[0,2\pi)$ to unitary matrices since $e^{iH}$ has the same eigenvectors as $H$, and the eigenvalues are the exponentials of those of $H$.
